# Android Notification Prevent Overwriting

Tags: android, notifications

In my application my user gets notified when they are invited to a new event. I check for invites every so often and update accordingly. My question is this: **If a notification already exists is there a simple way to prevent it from getting updated?**

I will try to explain this further.

Say the app checks for event invites at 2:00 pm. The user has 2 invites, so 2 notifications are created. The user is away from the phone so he/she does not notice the notifications. My app then checks for notifications at 2:45 pm. The user still has the same 2 event invites, but instead of creating 2 updated notifications I want the original ones to stay. I want the 2 invite notifications to read 2:00 pm instead of 2:45 pm.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

What if you simply retain whether the invites have already been displayed? This way the 2 new invites are displayed at 2:00pm and regardless of the user's actions they will not be redisplayed at 2:45pm.

Answer (score 0):

Create a HashMap which maps from the name of the event that you've been invited to to the time at which the invite was received and every time your user gets an invite you just create a new key-value pair in the map. Then all you need to do when calling showNotification is check if the name of this event already exists in the keySet of the HashMap and if it does -> do not call showNotification() else -> showNotification(with name of event and the corresponding time at which the notification was received from your HashMap).